# javascript remove tr from table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw this question  before but I cannont get it to work.  I have the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
var i = $('#p_scents tr').size() + 1;

$('#addScnt').click(function() {
    scntDiv.append('<tr><td> <input type="text" name="model" id="model"/></td><td><input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"/></td><td> <input type="text" name="price" id="price"/></td><td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"/></td><td><a href="#" id="remScnt">Delete</a></td></tr>');   
    i++;
    return false;
});

//Remove button
$(document).on('click', '#remScnt', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

The remove function is not working  Please help  here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scumah/xtyFh/8/

here is my page code:

```
{embed="shared/_html_header"}
{embed="shared/_page_header"}

<style = "text/css">
{ font-family:Arial; }
h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
h2 a { color: #224f99; }
a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#802727; }
p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

input { padding:5px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; -web-kit-border-radius:4px; -khtml-border-radius:4px; }
</style>



<div id="main_body_content">





<h4>
<a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a>
</h4>
<table class="dynatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="p_scents">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="model" read-only id="model"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"/>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" name="price" id="price"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"/>
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
var i = $('#p_scents tr').size() + 1;

$('#addScnt').click(function() {
    scntDiv.append('<tr><td> <input type="text" name="model" id="model"/></td><td><input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"/></td><td> <input type="text" name="price" id="price"/></td><td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"/></td><td><a href="#" id="remScnt">Delete</a></td></tr>');   
    i++;
    return false;
});

//Remove button
$(document).on('click', '#remScnt', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});

</script>

</div>


</div><!--/main_body_content-->



{embed="shared/_page_footer"}
```

Comment: You mean the Remove button? Works for me.

Comment: Yeah the fiddle works fine but not on my page what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me as well - you have to add one first before it appears.

Comment: **Note:** ids must be unique

Comment: Works for me too. You need to include the page that isn't working. also have you tried the debug tool?

Comment: it's working fine for me. what the prblm on the code?

Comment: Have you added your script into document load? $(function () { // Add your code here });

Comment: How can I post my entire page code on here?

Comment: Any error in the console? And use class instead of ID for **remScnt** click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your problem and providing solution as per problem.

In your script the things happening before the All DOM elements generated and that's why events are not properly binding with elements. So you need to wrap your script in `document.ready()` event as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents tr').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').click(function () {
            scntDiv.append('<tr><td> <input type="text" name="model" id="model"/></td><td><input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"/></td><td> <input type="text" name="price" id="price"/></td><td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"/></td><td><a href="#" id="remScnt">Delete</a></td></tr>');
            i++;
            return false;
        });

        //Remove button

            $(document).on('click', '#remScnt', function () {
                if (i > 2) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                    i--;
                }
                return false;
            });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: @Dom have you included the Jquery file in your html?

Comment: BINGO! Thank you @ Bhavesh Kachhadiya

Answer (score 1):

`ID` must be unique in HTML, instead use a class as selector like `class="remScnt"`

Change your selector to

```
$(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function() {
```

Additionally, wrap your code in document-ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```